# Amazon SES can't send email to non-verified email address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send an email using Amazon SES. I've had this working with the `us-east-1` region and just switched my region to `eu-east-1` and I can't send an email to my personal gmail account. I have verified the `from` address, the error is explicitly asking to verifiy the `to` address, which seems super odd. What's going wrong here? If I change the `to` email to match the `from` it works, which is super odd.

> Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region

[image: https://monosnap.com/file/iEBW8CeMEEDpM1nZLGw6Y9NezNNn97.png]

Comment: See too https://stackoverflow.com/q/37528301/320594.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you have this at the top of your SES dashboard?[image]

If so it's because you need to request to be approved out of "sandbox" mode.

Comment: ...because each region is independent.  Having production access in one region doesn't mean you have it in another.